# Cannot infer lifetime for async method

Tags: rust, async-await, reference, lifetime

Consider the following code:

```
struct Base{
    value: u32
}

impl Base{
    async fn create_test_async(&self, some_string: &str) -> Option<Test>{ //error
        None
    }
    
    fn create_test(&self, some_string: &str) -> Option<Test>{ //ok
        None
    }
}

struct Test<'a>{
    value: &'a u32
}
```

[**Playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7bcb5241fabbbd12d85f50279817828f)

The `async fn create_test_async` fails to compile with the error:

```
error[E0726]: implicit elided lifetime not allowed here
 --> src/lib.rs:6:68
  |
6 |     async fn create_test_async(&self, some_string: &str) -> Option<Test>{
  |                                                                    ^^^^- help: indicate the anonymous lifetime: `<'_>`
```

Surely it can be fixed with specifying the lifetime parameter as

```
async fn create_test_async<'a>(&'a self, some_string: &str) -> Option<Test<'a>>{
    None
}
```

**QUESTION:** Why is it required to specify lifetime parameter explicitly for `async` methods? What stops rust from inferring it?

Comment: This seems to be a [well known limitation](https://docs.rs/async-trait/0.1.41/async_trait/#elided-lifetimes). I think that having generic lifetimes elided (other than `&'_`) is now considered a design flaw, because it hides the fact that there is a lifetime somewhere, so when adding the new `async` syntax the Rustc builders decided not to make the flaw bigger. I cannot find a reference for this, other than the _preferred_ hints in [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html). Hey, maybe this will become the norm in edition 2021...

Comment: It looks like there was the intention to deprecate this usage in [Rust 2018](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/ownership-and-lifetimes/the-anonymous-lifetime.html). But currently, not even clippy complains about it.